# Protect pages by raising 404

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, and I want to protect certain pages by raising 404 if request is not from certain login user.

I already foreginkey topic to user. Here is the code to protect topic page.

```
@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

I wonder are there better ways if I want to protect a lot of pages so I don't have to add the same code in every function?

Comment: 403 would be more appropriate than 404.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 404 is perfectly valid if you don't want to indicate the *existence* of records with these ids in the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you definitely want to raise 404, a quicker method would be to make the user check part of the query itself - then your can use the [`get_object_or_404` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id, owner=request.uset)
```